# I get an error saying " Could not find the task 'C/C++: g++.exe build active file'

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, gdb

I've tried most things on Stack Overflow including messing around with external console values, using a previous version of C/C++ extensions, changing cppbuild to shell, etc. Nothing seems to make it work. If I press debug anyway, I get an error saying the launch program '....launch.exe' does not exist.

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is my task.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
          "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
          "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
      },
      {
        "label": "run make",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make"
      },
      {
        "label": "run make test",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make test"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: In your first json file you have `C/C++: g++.exe build active file` while in your second you have `C/C++: gcc.exe build active file`.

Comment: Are you trying to compile c or c++? Please don't tag both. If c++ you need to use g++ not gcc

Comment: You can set the launch.json `preLaunchTask` and the tasks.json `label` to something more easily readable or easy to check, like `build-app` or `build-debug`.

Answer (score 0):

"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file" in launch.json, should be consistent with "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file" in tasks.json.